# Demultiplexing symmetric PacBio reads

Tags: sequence-analysis

I have PacBio CCS.h5 and the corresponding fasta and fastq files and I would like to demultiplex them. Does anyone know of how this can be done in the absence of bas.h5 files.

Thanks for your help!

Mandy

Comment: It is more likely that you will get an answer over at biostars.org. Not that it is wrong here, but this place is dedicated to bioinformatics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a specific problem in a specialized software environment.

Comment: @Chris Stronks, Which software are you referring to? I am not sure how familiar you are with PacBio and demultiplexing but in my opinion, the question fits within the topic of sequence-analysis.

Comment: Do you mean demuxing the FASTQ into the FASTA and QUAL streams? The FASTA format only contains one data stream, so I don't see what you want to demux out of it.